# Can not build maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have cloned the [zerocracy](https://github.com/zerocracy/farm) project and am trying to build it as described in the README using `mvn clean install -Pqulice,codenarc -e`. But I can't do it, although I haven't changed anything in the repository. This is my first time using maven. Perhaps I forgot to do something obvious?

This is the output I am getting:

```
C:\Users\ruca\farm>mvn clean install -Pqulice,codenarc -e
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.zerocracy:farm:jar:0.30.7
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.(groupId:artifactId:type:classifier)' must be unique: org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles:tyrus-standalone-client:jar -> duplicate declaration of version 1.13.1 @ line 361, column 17
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< com.zerocracy:farm >-------------------------
[INFO] Building farm 0.30.7
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.2.Final has been relocated to org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.2.Final
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ farm ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ farm ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (jcabi-build-number) @ farm ---
[INFO] ShortRevision tag detected. The value is '7'.
[INFO] Executing: cmd.exe /X /C "git rev-parse --verify --short=7 HEAD"
[INFO] Working directory: C:\Users\ruca\farm
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.840 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-09-11T17:28:18+07:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (jcabi-build-number) on project farm: Cannot get the revision information from the scm repository : 
[ERROR] Exception while executing SCM command.: Error while executing command. Error while executing process. Cannot run program "git" (in directory "C:\Users\ruca\farm"): CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:buildnumber-maven-plugin:1.4:create (jcabi-build-number) on project farm: Cannot get the revision information from the scm repository : 
Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot get the revision information from the scm repository : 
Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision (CreateMojo.java:685)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute (CreateMojo.java:397)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Exception while executing SCM command.
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:63)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.executeCommand (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.info (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.info (AbstractScmMojo.java:284)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.getScmRevision (AbstractScmMojo.java:293)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision (CreateMojo.java:670)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute (CreateMojo.java:397)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)

                                                                                           )
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.scm.ScmException: Error while executing
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.GitCommandLineUtils.execute (GitCommandLineUtils.java:146)
    at o.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.info.GtInfoCommand.executeCommand (GitInfoCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.executeCommand (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:291)
at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.info (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.info (AbstractScmMojo.java:284)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.getScmRevision (AbstractScmMojo.java:293)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision (CreateMojo.java:670)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute (CreateMojo.java:397)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultldPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineException: Error while executing process.
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute (Commandline.java:675)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLineAsCallable (CommandLineUtils.java:134)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.GitCommandLineUtils.execute (GitCommandLineUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.info.GitInfoCommand.executeCommand (GitInfoCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.executeCommand (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.info (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.info (AbstractScmMojo.java:284)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.getScmRevision (AbstractScmMojo.java:293)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision (CreateMojo.java:670)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute (CreateMojo.java:397)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "git" (in directory "C:\Users\ruca\farm"): CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:620)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute (Commandline.java:670)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLineAsCallable (CommandLineUtils.java:134)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.GitCommandLineUtils.execute (GitCommandLineUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.info.GitInfoCommand.executeCommand (GitInfoCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.executeCommand (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.info (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.info (AbstractScmMojo.java:284)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.getScmRevision (AbstractScmMojo.java:293)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision (CreateMojo.java:670)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute (CreateMojo.java:397)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, Не удается найти указанный файл
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create (Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init> (ProcessImpl.java:386)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start (ProcessImpl.java:137)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start (ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec (Runtime.java:620)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.Commandline.execute (Commandline.java:670)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLineAsCallable (CommandLineUtils.java:134)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:105)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.util.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine (CommandLineUtils.java:74)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.GitCommandLineUtils.execute (GitCommandLineUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.gitexe.command.info.GitInfoCommand.executeCommand (GitInfoCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.command.AbstractCommand.execute (AbstractCommand.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.executeCommand (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:291)
    at org.apache.maven.scm.provider.git.AbstractGitScmProvider.info (AbstractGitScmProvider.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.info (AbstractScmMojo.java:284)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.AbstractScmMojo.getScmRevision (AbstractScmMojo.java:293)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.getRevision (CreateMojo.java:670)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.build.CreateMojo.execute (CreateMojo.java:397)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Any ideas what this means is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could this be the problem?

> Cannot run program "git" (in directory "C:\Users\ruca\farm"):
> CreateProcess error=2

Do you have `git` installed? Can it be run from the prompt? "error=2" often refers to a missing file.

Comment: Thanks, I had git, but I forgot to add it to the PATH variable